# how to extract binary data from stringstream variable in c++?

Tags: c++

I am new in C++, I usually use C. But now, I just find a good library that compress some information, with a special algorithm that it is very useful to my project. Then this library gave me as an answer: binary data which lives in a stringstream object. Since it is binary data, there are some bytes that are not an ASCII character. So what I want to do is extract the data and got their hexadecimal representation. How I can do it?
I have the following code:

```
stringstream ss; \\variable in which I got the result from the library
bitset1.write(ss); \\with this instruction I got the binary information from the library
```

From there I try the following things:

1) Just print:

```
cout << hex << ss;
```

2) Use the str method.

```
cout << hex << ss.str();
```

3) Use the read buffer method.

```
cout << hex << ss.rdbuf();
```

So, I think I am missing something, or maybe a lot, someone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

If a shortcut exists, I do not know it.  However, this does what you want:

```
std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
const std::string s = ss.str();
const size_t slen = s.length();
for (size_t i = 0; i < slen; ++i) {
    const unsigned char c = s[i];
    const unsigned int n = c;
    std::cout << std::setw(2) << n;
}
std::cout << "\n";
```

The key is to use a non-`char` integer type for output, since the stream insertion operator `<<` treats `char` specially.

Comment: Calling `ss.str()` repeatedly is abysmal for efficiency. Call it once and cache it.

Comment: @thb it works perfectly well thanks a lot, also I just callit once ss.str(). Now, i just will like to know how to do the invers process if I have a string how I load a StringStream variable?

Comment: @user1462592 : `std::stringstream ss(my_string_object);` [It's not like documentation isn't readily available...](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream)

Comment: @ildjarn well in did the question is: how to load a String that has hexadecimal representation of a binary data to a stringstream

Comment: @user1462592 : I showed exactly how in the comment you just replied to.

Comment: To my surprise, @ildjarn is right.  I have verified it on GCC 4.4 with the optimizer disabled.  [I had made a false assumption regarding the implementation of `std::ostringstream::str()`.]

Comment: My original answer output only characters 0 <= c < 128 correctly.  I have modified it to handle other 8-bit characters correctly as well, adding the `unsigned char` line you now see above.